# Collison not working

Tags: javascript

I tried to do a collision prototype for my gem object and every time my player interacts with it, it doesn't reset. Dev tools isn't coming up with any errors as well.

```
var checkCollisions = function(targets){
    var target;
    if (Array.isArray(targets)){
        for (var i =0; i < targets.length; i++){
            target = targets[i];
            if (targets === allEnemies){
                target.width = 50;
                target.height = 40;
            }
            if (player.x < target.x + target.width && player.x + player.width  > target.x && player.y < target.y + target.height && player.y + player.height > target.y){
                console.count('collision');

              player.reset();
              return true;

            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};

var Gem = function(x,y){
  this.x = [2,275,300];
  this.y = [200,150,80];
  this.width = 50;
  this.height = 40;
  this.sprite = 'images/gem-blue.png';

}

Gem.prototype.update = function(){

    this.x = 200
    this.y = 200

};

Gem.prototype.render = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y);

};



Gem.prototype.reset = function(){

  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;

};

Gem.prototype.checkCollision = function(player) {

  for(var i = 0; i  player.length; i++){
    if(player.x < this.x + this.width &&
    player.x + player.width > this.x &&
    player.y < this.y + this.height &&
    player.height + player.y > this.y);
}
    console.log("got a gem!");

    gem.reset();
};






var gem = new Gem();
```

Comment: `targets` is a local variable (containing an array of objects?), `if (targets === allEnemies)` will never pass.

Comment: You never define `allEnemies`, so most likely this code will generate a `ReferenceError`. We also can't see where you are instantiating a `Gem` object, or where you are invoking `checkCollisions`.

Comment: i have a link to my gitrepo, https://github.com/Jcook894/frontend-nanodegree-arcade-game